# Git ssh access on windows

Tags: windows, git, ssh, gitlab, git-bash

I have set-up a repository at a Gitlab cloud server (linux-based). I created a new repo there following the basic instructions.

```
git@code.example.com:mike/repo.git
```

I add the repo as a remote to my local git

```
git remote add gitlab git@code.example.com:mike/repo.git
```

I have generated a (pk, sk) key-pair using Puttygen on a windows machine.  I add these in Users/mike/.ssh as id_rsa follwing the instructions from

https://serverfault.com/questions/194567/how-do-i-tell-git-for-windows-where-to-find-my-private-rsa-key

Furthermore, I add the public key under DeployKeys for the repository in Gitlab.

Unfortunately, when I try (in Git bash)

```
git push -u gitlab master
```

it stills asks for my git user password
git@code.example.com:mike/repo.git's password?

when I try

```
ssh -v git@code.example.com:mike/repo.git
```

it comes back with
ssh: Could not resolve hostname code.example.com:mike/repo.git: no address associated with name

Not clear what I am missing. Any thoughts?

Cheers, Mike

Comment: In your bash session, do you see your keys when you do a ls $HOME/.ssh?

Comment: Yes, I see id_rsa (secure key) in my .ssh. Not my public key

Comment: Well, you need both (private and public keys) in there.

Comment: I followed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224066/how-to-convert-ssh-keypairs-generated-using-puttygenwindows-into-key-pairs-use to create the public key, but still asks for my password...

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the User Profile
2. Click ssh keys on the left menu
3. Add your ssh
   key

[image: Add SSH key]

Comment: I tried this, but still asks for my password. I also tried to add it to my project via Deploy keys. However, then it complains about already existing key. I don't seem to be able to have the same key enabled at my profile and for he project

Comment: Try to store your credentials `git config credential.helper store`

Comment: No luck. It is likely a general ssh problem. I also cannot ssh -v localhost (leading to connection refused).