# using git bash with putty to push-pull

Tags: git, putty, git-bash

I want to use the Git bash in windows in order to push-pull my project.
I have a ssh key that I use with putty.

With Git extensions my repository works well, I can do all operation as I want.
I've putty in my taskbar and my key is registered.

When I open the console and I try to `push/pull` git asks me for the password, but I've don't have one (the ssh key password does not work).

I've tried with `git config -l` and my remote url is `git@server.ip.address/repository.git` so I'm not using a http connection (I think).

How can I access to the remote through the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to check from your git bash session in Windows is the environment variable `HOME`.

It must be set (usually to `%USERPROFILE%`) in order to include `%HOME%\.ssh`(`\id_rsa`/`id_rsa.pub`)

If `%HOME%` is properly set (type `set HOME` to check its value), ssh operations will work.

The presumes you are using openssh, not putty, which means you need to convert your ppk key into a [public/private openssh set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2224204/6309), to be copied in `%HOME%\.ssh`.

Comment: I don't have a .pub file. I've a .ppk key generated with putty. Inside my .ssh folder there's only `known_hosts`. I put my ppk key in another folder.

Comment: @Jepessen don't use putty: use openssh (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2224204/6309). But in any case, HOME must be defined.

Comment: Ok I'll try with openssh. I'll let you know. thanks.

Comment: @Jepessen maybe check first if this works, *before* accepting the answer ;)

Comment: I've checked to another site and with a colleague and they do the same way. I've faith...

Comment: It worked, thanks! The only thing that I had to do was to convert using `puttygen` my `.ppk` key to a openssh private key in order to put is into `.ssh` as you say. Can you add it to your answer for completeness? thanks.

Comment: @Jepessen Great! I have edited the answer as requested.