# How to load PuTTYgen keys in Bouncy castle

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, putty

I'm playing around with encrypting. I have got stucked on loading the keys with BouncyCastle. The keys have been generated by PuTTYgen (SSH-2 RSA 4096 bit). Is there maybe some other way to load it?

```
PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa
Encryption: aes256-cbc
Comment: rsa-key-20160508
Public-Lines: 12
```

I get:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll
> Additional information: unexpected end-of-contents marker*"

```
const string pubkey = @"AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAgEAlX+AsmDF7FoR7D2jWYJTKLD6ZH6FAY9v2vPa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";

const string prikey = @"...";

var publickey = Convert.FromBase64String(pubkey);
//var privatekey = Convert.FromBase64String(prikey);

Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.AsymmetricKeyParameter publicAsymmetricKey = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey(publickey);
//Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.AsymmetricKeyParameter privateAsymmetricKey = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.PrivateKeyFactory.CreateKey(privatekey);
```

**ADDED:**
I generated a new key with  "ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096" and tryed to load it with pemreader:

```
   const string pubkey = @"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";
    
   var pemReader = new Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader(new StringReader(pubkey));
   // KeyParameter is still null
   var KeyParameter = (Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.AsymmetricKeyParameter)pemReader.ReadObject();
```

**ADDED:**

I was able to generate a public key and also load a unencrypted private key
(https://rietta.com/blog/2012/01/27/openssl-generating-rsa-key-from-command/)

> openssl genrsa -des3 -out private.pem 4096
>
> openssl rsa -in private.pem -outform PEM -pubout -out public.pem
>
> openssl rsa -in private.pem -out private_unencrypted.pem -outform PEM

```
var publickey = Convert.FromBase64String(pubkey);
var privatekey = Convert.FromBase64String(prikey);

var asnprivate = Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Asn1Object.FromStream(new MemoryStream(privatekey));
var privStruct = new Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Pkcs.RsaPrivateKeyStructure((Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Asn1Sequence)asnprivate);
   
AsymmetricKeyParameter publicAsymmetricKey = PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey(publickey);
```

But I was not able to load the encrypted private key...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the openssl PEM I was able to make it to work. I continue to find out how to load load the protected private key.

Thanks for all the input.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Pkcs;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1;

namespace EncryptTest1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string pubkey = @"MIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEAuQhcZKNnIC2bvJhI5Yzq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";
            const string prikey = @"MIIJKQIBAAKCAgEAuQhcZKNnIC2bvJhI5YzqoH9uGAHuiAt9bOXdIrsaeEwsIUMu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";

            var publickey = Convert.FromBase64String(pubkey);
            var privatekey = Convert.FromBase64String(prikey);

            var asnprivate = Asn1Object.FromStream(new MemoryStream(privatekey));
            var privStruct = new RsaPrivateKeyStructure((Asn1Sequence)asnprivate);

            RsaKeyParameters privateAsymmetricKey = new RsaKeyParameters(true, privStruct.Modulus, privStruct.PrivateExponent);
            RsaKeyParameters publicAsymmetricKey = (RsaKeyParameters)PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey(publickey);

            var inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("the message");

            Console.WriteLine("--- Message: ----");
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(inputBytes));

            IAsymmetricBlockCipher cipher = new RsaEngine();
            cipher.Init(true, publicAsymmetricKey);
            var cipheredBytes = cipher.ProcessBlock(inputBytes, 0, inputBytes.Length);

            Console.WriteLine("--- Enc utf8: ----");
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(cipheredBytes));

            Console.WriteLine("--- Enc Base64: ----");
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(cipheredBytes));

            cipher.Init(false, privateAsymmetricKey);
            var deciphered = cipher.ProcessBlock(cipheredBytes, 0, cipheredBytes.Length);

            Console.WriteLine("--- Dec: ----");
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(deciphered));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The PuTTY .ppk key format is proprietary to PuTTY.

I'm pretty sure there's no support for .ppk files in Bouncy castle.

You need to convert your keys to OpenSSH format. For that see [How to convert SSH keypairs generated using PuttyGen(Windows) into key-pairs used by ssh-agent and KeyChain(Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2224066/850848).