# SSH connection using private key authentication in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, ssh, private-key

I was given a `ppk` to access the server of my client. It was working perfectly using puTTY in windows as I can easily browse the private key. However, I need to access the server in Ubuntu environment I tried the command

ssh -i /path/to/private_key.ppk user@myserver.com

But it was asking for paraphrase which I wasn't ask when connecting using PuTTY in Windows.

Comment: The standard ssh client does not accept ppk keys as used by putty. You have to convert that key to a normal format. There and many tutorials for that on the internet, you can do it with the openssh version you have installed, no additional software required.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert SSH keypairs generated using PuttyGen(Windows) into key-pairs used by ssh-agent and KeyChain(Linux)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224066/how-to-convert-ssh-keypairs-generated-using-puttygenwindows-into-key-pairs-use)