# Not able to add SSH Key in Jenkins Configuration

Tags: jenkins, ssh

I Have installed 'Publish Over SSH' plugin in Jenkins and would like to transfer few files to SSH Server after each Build .

I have generated the private key using `puttygen` with passphrase and have given the OpenSSH Public Key in 'authorization_keys' in SSH Server.

Using the generated private key and passphrase , I'm able to login to the SSH Server through PuTTY.

But in Jenkins I'm not able to add the SSH Key. Getting the below Error.

> jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Failed to add SSH key. Message [The cipher 'aes256-cbc' is required, but it is not available.

[image: Jenkins Configuration]

Comment: Try to generate ssh-keys with `ssh-keygen` instead of `puttygen`

Answer (score 10):

Most of the tools (including Jenkins) support keys in OpenSSH format (generated using `ssh-keygen`), not in the PuTTY format (generated using PuTTYgen). Generate a new key using `ssh-keygen` or convert the PPK to OpenSSH format.

I wrote the following information in the SO Documentation.

---

#### Convert PPK (PuTTY key) to OpenSSH format

You might receive from your peer private key in PPK format, which seems it does not work in OpenSSH (command-line `ssh`). The client will be asking for the passphrase, because of [OpenSSH bug](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2522).

```
$ ssh -i mykey.ppk example.com
Enter passphrase for mykey.ppk:
```

You need to convert the key to OpenSSH format using PuTTYgen (command-line version):

```
puttygen mykey.ppk -o mykey.key -O private-openssh
```

Or in GUI version:

- Open PuttyGen
- Click Load
- Load your private key
- Go to **Conversions**->**Export OpenSSH** and export your private key
- Copy your private key to `~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Source: [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2224204/2196426), [Unix SE answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/323000/121504)