# Authenticate server to Bitbucket using SSH-keys

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, ssh-keys

How is it possible to register a public key to the regarding Bitbucket account and a private key on a remote server to enable pull requests without asking for a password?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html

Comment: I know to to use ssh to communicate between my local client and bitbucket. My problem is to use a private key on remote host.

Comment: Then you need to configure ssh authentication in your remote host as well & add that key to the bitbucket too

Comment: Yes of course. But how?

Comment: Exactly the same way you already did locally. Generate a key pair remotely, download the public key to local and register it on Bitbucket as usual.

Comment: I generated the key locally and added it manuelly to .ssh.
This is the mistake, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

1. Be sure you have ssh installed
2. Generate Keypair using ssh-keygen
3. Check if ssh-agent is runnung by executing 'eval $(ssh-agent -s)'
4. Add ssh-key to your ssh-agent using 'ssh-add [path-to-your-privatekey]'
5. Add your publickey to you Bitbucket-Accountsettings

Attention: If you use puttygen and/or OpenSSH you need to follow this steps
[Convert key to OpenSSH format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224066/how-to-convert-ssh-keypairs-generated-using-puttygenwindows-into-key-pairs-use)