# Authentication with PPK key in SSH.NET

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, sftp, ssh.net

I'm creating a window service for downloading files from an SFTP server. For that I'm using `Renci.SshNet` , `Renci.SshNet.Common` and `Renci.SshNet.Sftp` .

I have this code:

```
String Host = "HostName";
int Port = 22;
String RemoteFileDirectory =
    Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SourcePath"]);
String Username = "UserName";
String Password = "*******";

var KeybasedMethod = new KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod(Username);
KeybasedMethod.AuthenticationPrompt +=
    (sender, e) => { e.Prompts.First().Response = password; };

AuthenticationMethod[] methods = new AuthenticationMethod[] 
{
    new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(Username, new PrivateKeyFile(@"Z:\SFTP SETUP\CJ22")),
    KeybasedMethod
};
ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(hostname, username, methods);

using (var sftp = new SftpClient(connectionInfo))
{
    sftp.Connect();
    // ...
}
```

I get exception.

> Invalid private key file.

I can't figure it out that what I'm missing in my code.

Below is the log file I'm getting at the time when I login to server from my client machine using FileZilla.

```
2017-04-03 16:25:19 8120 3 Status: Connecting to abc.domainname.com... 
2017-04-03 16:25:19 8120 3 Trace: Going to execute "C:\Program Files\FileZilla FTP Client\fzsftp.exe" 
2017-04-03 16:25:19 8120 3 Response: fzSftp started 
2017-04-03 16:25:19 8120 3 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::ConnectParseResponse(fzSftp started) 
2017-04-03 16:25:19 8120 3 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::SendNextCommand() 
2017-04-03 16:25:19 8120 3 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::ConnectSend() 
2017-04-03 16:25:19 8120 3 Command: keyfile "Z:\SFTP SETUP\CJ21_PVT.ppk" 
2017-04-03 16:25:19 8120 3 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::ConnectParseResponse() 
2017-04-03 16:25:19 8120 3 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::SendNextCommand() 
2017-04-03 16:25:19 8120 3 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::ConnectSend() 
2017-04-03 16:25:19 8120 3 Command: keyfile "Z:\SFTP SETUP\CJ22_PVT.ppk" 
2017-04-03 16:25:19 8120 3 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::ConnectParseResponse() 
2017-04-03 16:25:19 8120 3 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::SendNextCommand() 
2017-04-03 16:25:19 8120 3 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::ConnectSend() 
2017-04-03 16:25:19 8120 3 Command: keyfile "Z:\SFTP SETUP\CJ24_PVT.ppk" 
2017-04-03 16:25:19 8120 3 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::ConnectParseResponse() 
2017-04-03 16:25:19 8120 3 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::SendNextCommand() 
2017-04-03 16:25:19 8120 3 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::ConnectSend() 
2017-04-03 16:25:19 8120 3 Command: keyfile "Z:\SFTP SETUP\CJ90_PVT.ppk" 
2017-04-03 16:25:19 8120 3 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::ConnectParseResponse() 
2017-04-03 16:25:19 8120 3 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::SendNextCommand() 
2017-04-03 16:25:19 8120 3 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::ConnectSend() 
2017-04-03 16:25:19 8120 3 Command: open "CJ22@abc.domainname.com" 22 
2017-04-03 16:25:19 8120 3 Trace: Looking up host "abc.domainname.com" 
2017-04-03 16:25:19 8120 3 Trace: Connecting to xxx.xxx.163.74 port 22 
2017-04-03 16:25:23 8120 3 Trace: Server version: SSH-2.0-1.82_sshlib Globalscape 
2017-04-03 16:25:23 8120 3 Trace: Using SSH protocol version 2 
2017-04-03 16:25:23 8120 3 Trace: We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Local:_Mar_28_2014_10:34:48 
2017-04-03 16:25:24 8120 3 Trace: Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange 
2017-04-03 16:25:24 8120 3 Trace: Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-1 
2017-04-03 16:25:25 8120 3 Trace: Host key fingerprint is: 
2017-04-03 16:25:25 8120 3 Trace: ssh-rsa 2048 6b:80:2c:5e:af:3f:2c:c7:f7:ef:4b:dd:85:55:32:fe 
2017-04-03 16:25:25 8120 3 Trace: Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption 
2017-04-03 16:25:25 8120 3 Trace: Initialised HMAC-SHA1 client->server MAC algorithm 
2017-04-03 16:25:25 8120 3 Trace: Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption 
2017-04-03 16:25:25 8120 3 Trace: Initialised HMAC-SHA1 server->client MAC algorithm 
2017-04-03 16:25:25 8120 3 Trace: Successfully loaded 4 key pairs from file 
2017-04-03 16:25:26 8120 3 Trace: Offered public key from "Z:\SFTP SETUP\CJ21_PVT.ppk" 
2017-04-03 16:25:26 8120 3 Trace: Server refused public key 
2017-04-03 16:25:26 8120 3 Trace: Offered public key from "Z:\SFTP SETUP\CJ22_PVT.ppk" 
2017-04-03 16:25:26 8120 3 Trace: Offer of public key accepted, trying to authenticate using it. 
2017-04-03 16:25:29 8120 3 Trace: Further authentication required 
2017-04-03 16:25:30 8120 3 Trace: Using keyboard-interactive authentication. inst_len: 0, num_prompts: 1 
2017-04-03 16:25:30 8120 3 Command: Pass: ********* 
2017-04-03 16:25:30 8120 3 Trace: Access granted 
2017-04-03 16:25:30 8120 3 Trace: Opened channel for session 
2017-04-03 16:25:31 8120 3 Trace: Started a shell/command 
2017-04-03 16:25:31 8120 3 Status: Connected to abc.domainname.com 
2017-04-03 16:25:33 8120 3 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::ConnectParseResponse() 
2017-04-03 16:25:33 8120 3 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0) 
2017-04-03 16:25:33 8120 3 Trace: CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0) 
2017-04-03 16:25:33 8120 3 Trace: CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0) 
2017-04-03 16:25:33 8120 3 Status: Retrieving directory listing... 
2017-04-03 16:25:33 8120 3 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::SendNextCommand() 
2017-04-03 16:25:33 8120 3 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::ChangeDirSend() 
2017-04-03 16:25:33 8120 3 Command: cd "/" 
2017-04-03 16:25:34 8120 3 Response: New directory is: "/" 
2017-04-03 16:25:34 8120 3 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0) 
2017-04-03 16:25:34 8120 3 Trace: CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0) 
2017-04-03 16:25:34 8120 3 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::ParseSubcommandResult(0) 
2017-04-03 16:25:34 8120 3 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::ListSubcommandResult() 
2017-04-03 16:25:34 8120 3 Trace: state = 1 
2017-04-03 16:25:34 8120 3 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::SendNextCommand() 
2017-04-03 16:25:34 8120 3 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::ListSend() 
2017-04-03 16:25:34 8120 3 Trace: state = 2 
2017-04-03 16:25:34 8120 3 Command: ls 
2017-04-03 16:25:34 8120 3 Status: Listing directory / 
2017-04-03 16:25:36 8120 3 Listing: drwxrw-rw- 1 user group 0 Mar 24 2015 JKOB1 
2017-04-03 16:25:36 8120 3 Listing: drwxrw-rw- 1 user group 0 Apr 3 10:40 JKOB 
2017-04-03 16:25:36 8120 3 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::ListParseResponse() 
2017-04-03 16:25:36 8120 3 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::SendNextCommand() 
2017-04-03 16:25:36 8120 3 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::ListSend() 
2017-04-03 16:25:36 8120 3 Trace: state = 3 
2017-04-03 16:25:36 8120 3 Status: Calculating timezone offset of server... 
2017-04-03 16:25:36 8120 3 Command: mtime "JKOB" 
2017-04-03 16:25:37 8120 3 Response: 1491216040 
2017-04-03 16:25:37 8120 3 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::ListParseResponse(1491216040) 
2017-04-03 16:25:37 8120 3 Status: Timezone offsets: Server: 0 seconds. Local: 19800 seconds. Difference: 19800 seconds. 
2017-04-03 16:25:37 8120 3 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0) 
2017-04-03 16:25:37 8120 3 Trace: CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0) 
2017-04-03 16:25:37 8120 3 Status: Directory listing successful 
2017-04-03 16:25:37 8120 3 Trace: CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0) 
2017-04-03 16:27:24 8120 3 Status: Disconnected from server 
2017-04-03 16:27:24 8120 3 Trace: CControlSocket::DoClose(64) 
2017-04-03 16:27:24 8120 3 Trace: CSftpControlSocket::ResetOperation(66) 
2017-04-03 16:27:24 8120 3 Trace: CControlSocket::ResetOperation(66) 
2017-04-03 16:27:24 8120 3 Trace: CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(66) 
2017-04-03 16:27:24 8120 3 Trace: CControlSocket::DoClose(64) 
2017-04-03 16:27:24 8120 3 Trace: CControlSocket::DoClose(64) 
2017-04-03 16:27:24 8120 3 Trace: CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
```

I've tried multiple solution from here and from other sources one after another but none of them worked. If you've any suggestion then it's more than welcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SSH.NET does not support .ppk key files. You have to use PuTTYgen to convert the .ppk key to OpenSSH format.

See [How to convert SSH keypairs generated using PuTTYgen (Windows) into key-pairs used by ssh-agent and Keychain (Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2224066/850848).

---

*Original answer, before the question was edited:*

You are using multifactor private key and keyboard interactive authentication in FileZilla:

> 2017-04-03 16:25:26 8120 3 Trace: Offered public key from "Z:\SFTP SETUP\CJ22_PVT.ppk"
>   2017-04-03 16:25:26 8120 3 Trace: Offer of public key accepted, trying to authenticate using it.
>   2017-04-03 16:25:29 8120 3 Trace: Further authentication required
>   2017-04-03 16:25:30 8120 3 Trace: Using keyboard-interactive authentication. inst_len: 0, num_prompts: 1
>   2017-04-03 16:25:30 8120 3 Command: Pass: *********
>   2017-04-03 16:25:30 8120 3 Trace: Access granted

While, you are using simple password authentication in your code:

```
using (var sftp = new SftpClient(Host, Port, Username, Password))
```

How can you even expect this to work?

---

To implement multifactor authentication, you have to use `ConnectionInfo`.

```
var keybInterMethod = new KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod(username);
keybInterMethod.AuthenticationPrompt +=
    (sender, e) => { e.Prompts.First().Response = password; };

AuthenticationMethod[] methods = new AuthenticationMethod[] {
    new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(username, new PrivateKeyFile(privateKey)),
    keybInterMethod
};
ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(hostname, username, methods);

using (var sftp = new SftpClient(connectionInfo))
{
    sftp.Connect();

    // ...
}
```