# Getting 'Permission denied (password).' when doing multi-factor authentication (key and password) in SSH.NET

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, sftp, ssh.net

I know this question has already been asked on other posts, but I couldn't find any satisfying answer.

I'm using the Renci.SSH (SSH.NET version 2016.1.0 in C#) to connect to SFTP. I have an SFTP server which I connect using an SSH key and password.

When I connect through WinSCP on my computer, it works perfectly. I would like to do the same from my C# code but I get:

> Renci.SshNet.Common.SshAuthenticationException: 'Permission denied (password).'

My PPP file was generated by PuTTYgen and it seems that Renci.SSH doesn't support PuTTY format. Actually, using the ppk file as it is, I get a:

> Renci.SshNet.Common.SshException: 'Invalid private key file.'.

So, I had to  convert my .ppk to OpenSSH format using the PuTTY key generator *Conversions --> Export OpenSSH Key using RSA*.

Here bellow an example of the resulting .ppk file:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Then I connect to the SFTP server as follow:

```
private static void CreateSftpSession(FtpConnectionSettings settings, Action<IFtpSession> onSessionOpen)
{

    var methods = new List<AuthenticationMethod>();
    methods.Add(new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(settings.UserName, settings.UserPassword));

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.PrivateKeyPath))
    {
        var keyFiles = new[] { new PrivateKeyFile(settings.PrivateKeyPath) };
        methods.Add(new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(settings.UserName, keyFiles));
    }

    var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(settings.Host, settings.Port, settings.UserName, methods.ToArray());

    using (SftpClient sftpClient = new SftpClient(connectionInfo))
    {

        SftpSession sftpSession = new SftpSession(sftpClient);
        sftpClient.Connect();
        onSessionOpen(sftpSession);
        sftpClient.Disconnect();
    }
}
```

At the call of `sftpClient.Connect()`, the exception is thrown.

Do you see anything wrong in what I'm doing?

Thanks a lot for your help

Here below the log of a successful WinSCP connection as requested:

> . 2019-12-10 14:54:45.922
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------- . 2019-12-10 14:54:45.922 WinSCP Version 5.15.9 (Build 10071) (OS
>   10.0.17763 - Windows 10 Enterprise) . 2019-12-10 14:54:45.922 Configuration: HKCU\Software\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2\ . 2019-12-10
>   14:54:45.922 Log level: Normal . 2019-12-10 14:54:45.922 Local
>   account: XXXX\xxx . 2019-12-10 14:54:45.922 Working directory:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP . 2019-12-10 14:54:45.922 Process ID:
>   20716 . 2019-12-10 14:54:45.923 Command-line: "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe"  . 2019-12-10 14:54:45.923 Time zone:
>   Current: GMT+1, Standard: GMT+1 (W. Europe Standard Time), DST: GMT+2
>   (W. Europe Daylight Time), DST Start: 3/31/2019, DST End: 10/27/2019 .
>   2019-12-10 14:54:45.923 Login time: Tuesday, December 10, 2019 2:54:45
>   PM . 2019-12-10 14:54:45.923
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------- . 2019-12-10 14:54:45.923 Session name: my_ftp_user@my_ftp_host.com
>   (Site) . 2019-12-10 14:54:45.923 Host name: my_ftp_host.com (Port:
>   6671) . 2019-12-10 14:54:45.924 User name: my_ftp_user (Password: Yes,
>   Key file: Yes, Passphrase: No) . 2019-12-10 14:54:45.924 Tunnel: No .
>   2019-12-10 14:54:45.924 Transfer Protocol: SFTP (SCP) . 2019-12-10
>   14:54:45.924 Ping type: Off, Ping interval: 30 sec; Timeout: 15 sec .
>   2019-12-10 14:54:45.924 Disable Nagle: No . 2019-12-10 14:54:45.924
>   Proxy: None . 2019-12-10 14:54:45.924 Send buffer: 262144 . 2019-12-10
>   14:54:45.924 SSH protocol version: 2; Compression: No . 2019-12-10
>   14:54:45.924 Bypass authentication: No . 2019-12-10 14:54:45.924 Try
>   agent: Yes; Agent forwarding: No; TIS/CryptoCard: No; KI: Yes; GSSAPI:
>   Yes . 2019-12-10 14:54:45.924 GSSAPI: Forwarding: No; Libs:
>   gssapi32,sspi,custom; Custom:  . 2019-12-10 14:54:45.924 Ciphers:
>   aes,chacha20,blowfish,3des,WARN,arcfour,des; Ssh2DES: No . 2019-12-10
>   14:54:45.924 KEX:
>   ecdh,dh-gex-sha1,dh-group14-sha1,rsa,WARN,dh-group1-sha1 . 2019-12-10
>   14:54:45.924 SSH Bugs:
>   Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto .
>   2019-12-10 14:54:45.924 Simple channel: Yes . 2019-12-10 14:54:45.924
>   Return code variable: Autodetect; Lookup user groups: Auto .
>   2019-12-10 14:54:45.924 Shell: default . 2019-12-10 14:54:45.924 EOL:
>   LF, UTF: Auto . 2019-12-10 14:54:45.924 Clear aliases: Yes, Unset
>   nat.vars: Yes, Resolve symlinks: Yes; Follow directory symlinks: No .
>   2019-12-10 14:54:45.924 LS: ls -la, Ign LS warn: Yes, Scp1 Comp: No;
>   Exit code 1 is error: No . 2019-12-10 14:54:45.924 SFTP Bugs:
>   Auto,Auto . 2019-12-10 14:54:45.924 SFTP Server: default . 2019-12-10
>   14:54:45.924 Local directory: \xxxx.xxx\xxx\RFs\xxx\Documents, Remote
>   directory: /log, Update: Yes, Cache: Yes . 2019-12-10 14:54:45.924
>   Cache directory changes: Yes, Permanent: Yes . 2019-12-10 14:54:45.924
>   Recycle bin: Delete to: No, Overwritten to: No, Bin path:  .
>   2019-12-10 14:54:45.924 DST mode: Unix . 2019-12-10 14:54:45.924
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------- . 2019-12-10 14:54:45.965 Looking up host "my_ftp_host.com" for SSH
>   connection . 2019-12-10 14:54:45.999 Connecting to 64.209.89.13 port
>   6671 . 2019-12-10 14:54:46.103 We claim version:
>   SSH-2.0-WinSCP_release_5.15.9 . 2019-12-10 14:54:46.206 Server
>   version: SSH-2.0-SSHD . 2019-12-10 14:54:46.206 Using SSH protocol
>   version 2 . 2019-12-10 14:54:46.206 Have a known host key of type rsa2
>   . 2019-12-10 14:54:46.206 Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange .
>   2019-12-10 14:54:46.701 Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash
>   SHA-256 . 2019-12-10 14:54:47.496 Host key fingerprint is: .
>   2019-12-10 14:54:47.496 ssh-rsa 2048
>   bc:37:d9:2a:15:93:3c:a6:a0:e9:88:5e:86:81:8d:43
>   mxhRidA9vIdsw+hmLZfFnLI/0BujM3kjJPrH5no9wGI= . 2019-12-10 14:54:47.503
>   Host key matches cached key . 2019-12-10 14:54:47.503 Initialised
>   AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption . 2019-12-10 14:54:47.503
>   Initialised HMAC-SHA1 client->server MAC algorithm . 2019-12-10
>   14:54:47.503 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption .
>   2019-12-10 14:54:47.503 Initialised HMAC-SHA1 server->client MAC
>   algorithm . 2019-12-10 14:54:47.707 Reading key file
>   "C:\Temp\AttribByStrategy\My_PrivateKey_wopp.ppk" . 2019-12-10
>   14:54:47.708 Pageant is running. Requesting keys. . 2019-12-10
>   14:54:47.708 Pageant has 0 SSH-2 keys . 2019-12-10 14:54:47.708
>   Configured key file not in Pageant ! 2019-12-10 14:54:47.708 Using
>   username "my_ftp_user". . 2019-12-10 14:54:58.649 Server offered these
>   authentication methods: password,publickey,keyboard-interactive .
>   2019-12-10 14:54:58.649 Offered public key . 2019-12-10 14:54:58.758
>   Offer of public key accepted ! 2019-12-10 14:54:58.758 Authenticating
>   with public key "rsa-key-20140520" . 2019-12-10 14:54:58.878 Sent
>   public key signature ! 2019-12-10 14:54:58.981 Further authentication
>   required . 2019-12-10 14:54:59.007 Further authentication required .
>   2019-12-10 14:54:59.007 Server offered these authentication methods:
>   password,keyboard-interactiveÀí½œt»Yªâ…©xÐ¾ñs€ç‘ð¾€Ó  .
>   2019-12-10 14:54:59.007 Attempting keyboard-interactive authentication
>   . 2019-12-10 14:54:59.110 Prompt (keyboard interactive, "SSH server:
>   Password Authentication", "Using keyboard-interactive
>   authentication.", "Password: ") . 2019-12-10 14:54:59.110 Using stored
>   password. . 2019-12-10 14:54:59.295 Access granted . 2019-12-10
>   14:54:59.295 Opening session as main channel . 2019-12-10 14:54:59.397
>   Opened main channel . 2019-12-10 14:54:59.641 Started a shell/command
>   . 2019-12-10 14:54:59.668
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------- . 2019-12-10 14:54:59.668 Using SFTP protocol. . 2019-12-10
>   14:54:59.668 Doing startup conversation with host.
>
> > 2019-12-10 14:54:59.684 Type: SSH_FXP_INIT, Size: 5, Number: -1 < 2019-12-10 14:54:59.786 Type: SSH_FXP_VERSION, Size: 33, Number: -1 .
> >     2019-12-10 14:54:59.786 SFTP version 3 negotiated. . 2019-12-10
> >     14:54:59.786 Unknown server extension newline@vandyke.com="\n" .
> >     2019-12-10 14:54:59.786 We believe the server has signed timestamps
> >     bug . 2019-12-10 14:54:59.786 We will use UTF-8 strings until server
> >     sends an invalid UTF-8 string as with SFTP version 3 and older UTF-8
> >     strings are not mandatory . 2019-12-10 14:54:59.786 Changing directory
> >     to "/log". . 2019-12-10 14:54:59.786 Getting real path for '/log'
> >     2019-12-10 14:54:59.786 Type: SSH_FXP_REALPATH, Size: 13, Number: 16 < 2019-12-10 14:54:59.897 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 49, Number: 16 .
> >     2019-12-10 14:54:59.897 Real path is '/log' . 2019-12-10 14:54:59.897
> >     Trying to open directory "/log".
> >     2019-12-10 14:54:59.897 Type: SSH_FXP_LSTAT, Size: 13, Number: 263 < 2019-12-10 14:55:00.003 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 29, Number: 263 .
> >     2019-12-10 14:55:00.004 Getting current directory name. . 2019-12-10
> >     14:55:00.073 Listing directory "/log".
> >     2019-12-10 14:55:00.073 Type: SSH_FXP_OPENDIR, Size: 13, Number: 523 < 2019-12-10 14:55:00.184 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 10, Number: 523
> >     2019-12-10 14:55:00.184 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 10, Number: 780 < 2019-12-10 14:55:00.286 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 205, Number: 780
> >     2019-12-10 14:55:00.286 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 10, Number: 1036 < 2019-12-10 14:55:00.388 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 17, Number:
> >     1036 < 2019-12-10 14:55:00.388 Status code: 1
> >     2019-12-10 14:55:00.388 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 10, Number: 1284 . 2019-12-10 14:55:00.388 ..;d;0;2016-11-27T05:00:00.000Z;3;"2123"
> >     [2123];"2020" [2020];rwxr-xr-x;0 . 2019-12-10 14:55:00.436 Startup
> >     conversation with host finished.

Comment: Yes, but actually the password is there and correctly defined. I used it when I connect manually

Comment: So you really mean that you use multifactor authentication (both **password** and **private** key)? Doesn't you mistake account **password** with **private key passphrase**?

Comment: Yes, I debugged the code to see if the variables are correctly defined. The file exists as it is the same I use form WinSCP from the same machine and user. And if the file was missing I would have a file not found exception. And the password is the account password and not the passphrase used to generate the key. I tried that also

Comment: Did you try putting the authentication methods in the order that WinSCP uses them? - the password after the key

Comment: Hello Martin, that was exactly the problem. The order  of the authentication methods in the methods List is important. I just added the PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod before the PasswordAuthenticationMethod and it worked fine. Thanks a lot and well done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in WinSCP log file, you should first authenticate with the private key and only then with the password:

> 2019-12-10 14:54:58.649 Server offered these authentication methods: password,publickey,keyboard-interactive
>   2019-12-10 14:54:58.649 Offered public key
>   2019-12-10 14:54:58.758 Offer of public key accepted
>   2019-12-10 14:54:58.758 Authenticating with public key "rsa-key-20140520"
>   2019-12-10 14:54:58.878 **Sent public key signature**
>   2019-12-10 14:54:59.007 **Further authentication required**
>   2019-12-10 14:54:59.007 Server offered these authentication methods: password,keyboard-interactive
>   2019-12-10 14:54:59.007 Attempting keyboard-interactive authentication
>   2019-12-10 14:54:59.110 Prompt (keyboard interactive, "SSH server: Password Authentication", "Using keyboard-interactive authentication.", "Password: ")
>   2019-12-10 14:54:59.110 **Using stored password.**

```
var methods = new List<AuthenticationMethod>();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.PrivateKeyPath))
{
    var keyFiles = new[] { new PrivateKeyFile(settings.PrivateKeyPath) };
    methods.Add(new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(settings.UserName, keyFiles));
}

methods.Add(new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(settings.UserName, settings.UserPassword));

var connectionInfo =
    new ConnectionInfo(settings.Host, settings.Port, settings.UserName, methods.ToArray());

using (SftpClient sftpClient = new SftpClient(connectionInfo))
{
    // ...
}
```

---

See also [Authentication with PPK key in SSH.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43176931/850848).