# GIT SSH public key error

Tags: git, ssh

I am trying to clone git repo using ssh I have git SSH fiel copied from another system where it is working  , but on this system it is giving error -

Cloning into 'repo'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Are you cloning from GitHub?

Comment: `ssh -vvv your-git-server`

Comment: @DilhanNakandala Github enterprise

Answer (score 0):

Check your private key permission first, ssh would not allow if it is accessible by others.

```
$ ls -l ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Then set the appropriate permissions

```
$ chown user:user ~/.ssh/id_rsa*
$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
$ chmod 644 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: It didn't work , even adding a new key also didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have the correct private key.

have you created a pair of private-pubic keys? 
if not you can follow the instructions [here](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-for-existing-ssh-keys/)

**Are you also using putty?** (you were asked in the installation of Git).
If so, follow the instructions above but generate the key with puttygen (and not with the command

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

)

after creating a pair, convert the putty-created public key to [OpenSSH format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2224204/6683217)
and then upload it to GitHub as your key.
The last step is to configure putty's default settings to use the private key generated by puttygen

[image]