# OSX SSH keys seem unavailable to git

Tags: git, macos, github, ssh

When I try and push commits up to GitHub, I get a

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Luckily, help.GitHub has [a great article on solving SSH issues.](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/) I ran through this guide and found that `ssh-add -l -E md5` returns `The agent has no identities.` The guide [says to generate a new key](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/), which I did. After that, `ssh-add` returns something like `2048 MD5:a0:dd:42:3c:5a:9d:e4:2a:21:52:4e:78:07:6e:c8:4d /Users/you/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)` as expected.

Great, I think, the problem's solved. I try another push, and get the same public key issue. I've made sure that my key is correctly set in GitHub. When I start a new session, `ssh-add` again returns no identities. I've even started the process from scratch following the article above. I've [checked my permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43732076/git-ssh-public-key-error), and now I'm out of troubleshooting leads.

Comment: It's hard to know what happened without a full log of your actions, the values they returned, etc. For instance, if you started a new agent, you may have loaded your key into *that* agent, and not Apple's one -- which would explain a new terminal not knowing anything about it.

Comment: ...so, all the instructions to run `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` actually *aren't* appropriate on MacOS: Keychain already gives you an agent shared with everything in your session.

Comment: BTW, one you have a key in your agent ("your agent" being Apple Keychain, not anything you manually invoked), use `ssh-add -L` (yes, *capital* `L`) to dump the public side, and make sure it's exactly that you have in github -- just to be sure that it's the same key in both places.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48502/how-can-i-permanently-add-my-ssh-private-key-to-keychain-so-it-is-automatically is probably worth running through -- note the `UseKeychain` directive.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Is there anything I can do to make this question more helpful? From my perspective, I was cruising along on a project, then one day I came back to it and no I can no longer push to GitHub, and I've no idea how to get back on track.

Comment: *shrug*. This would probably be neigh-trivial if I were actually present for an over-the-shoulder, but there are enough moving parts (or, rather, places where moving parts can *potentially* be configured in) and things that can *potentially* go wrong that it's a tricky one to describe full and complete troubleshooting steps in text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure your public key is [correctly registered on your GitHub profile](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/) (as one continuous line, without any newline in it).

Second, make sure to generate (at least for testing) a private key *not* protected by a passphrase: you need ssh agent only to manage keys with passphrase. If your key has no passphrase, you don't need ssh agent at all.

```
  ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "key for GitHub access" -q -P ""
```

That will replace your current key, so make sure you don't need your current key anymore.
[Test your key](https://help.github.com/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection/) with `ssh -T git@github.com`

Comment: Not using a passphrase was was the issue. I don't know why my key stopped working in the first place, but that got me up and running again! Thanks a bunch! Now I can work on figuring out why SSH-agent isn't behaving, and see if I can start using password protected keys again.

Comment: OS X behavior has changed.  You need to re-add your keys after each login/restart.