# SSH keys too short for Bitbucket: how to fix? (using sourcetree on windows)

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

So I am using sourcetree app and I'm using this guide (click [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html#SetupanSSHkey-ssh3)) for instructions on how to create a public key on my Windows machine.

When I copy the public key from Putty Key Generator into the SSH keys setting of Bitbucket, Bitbucket it complaining it's too short.

[image]

Looking back at Putty Key Generator, I am supposedly using 1024 bits.

[image]

I did notice that the public keys I'm seeing from the Putty app is much shorter than the ones I've gotten via ssh-keygen on my Mac/Ubuntu machines.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: Putty generates SSH keys in a different format and Bitbucket probably expects them in the OpenSSH format. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224066/how-to-convert-ssh-keypairs-generated-using-puttygenwindows-into-key-pairs-use

Comment: Use at least 2048 bits;1024-bit RSA keys are insecure. I would recommend 4096 bits, but that's preference. Also, see [this specific answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29344160/3397227) for how to get an OpenSSH format pubkey like @user3151902 said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.What i had to do was to change the number of bits at the very bottom..from 1024 to 2048.Then when I copied and add the new key to bitbucket it was long enough..

Answer (score 1):

To generate your key, use `<path\to\git>\usr\bin\ssh-keygen.exe`, packaged with [`git-for-windows/git`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) latest release:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f %USERPROFILE%\.ssh\id_rsa -C "key for GitLab access" -q -P ""
```

That will generate a correct key, without passphrase (at least for testing).
Make sure you don't need `id_rsa(.pub)` in your `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh` folder, if you had those keys before using the command above.