# "Error Message Invalid Key" WebStorm when connecting to Google Compute Engine instance as a remote server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, webstorm, ssh-keys

When I am trying to add `.ppk` file in WebStorm for getting remote server access for my Compute Engine instance I am getting an error in WebStorm:

> google_compute_engine.ppk is corrupt or has unknown format. Only SSH2
>   Keys in OpenSSH format (DSA, RSA, ECDSA) or PUTTY private Key *.ppk
>   are supported. Error Message Invalid Key : [xxxxxxxx]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through this post [how-to-convert-ssh-keypairs-generated-using-puttygenwindows-into-key-pairs-use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224066/how-to-convert-ssh-keypairs-generated-using-puttygenwindows-into-key-pairs-use) and then I did these steps.

1. open puttygen
2. Go to file and then load private key
3. Generate public/private key value pair click on generate.

Now use this newly generated key inside Webstorm.

Answer (score 0):

**Invalid**

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

**Correct**

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

**Step to fix**

Remove old files

```
rm -rf ~/.ssh/*
```

Create new File (-m pem)

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -m pem -f ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine -C username
```