# Gitpython - can't clone from remote repo using private ssh key

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, python-2.7, gitpython

I'm trying to clone a project from git using Python's Gitpython library, but instead of password i want to use ssh keys for authentication. I've created a pair of private and public keys and put the public in git and the private in the project directory. In my code i'm using the following commands:

My import:

```
from git import Repo
```

The clone command:

```
ssh_cmd = 'ssh -i private_key.ppk'
Repo.clone_from(GIT_USERS_URL, local_git_dir, env={'GIT_SSH_COMMAND': ssh_cmd})
```

'private_key.ppk' is the name of the private key file.

When running the script i get the following error:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I know this question has been asked a lot but none of the solutions worked and i don't see why ?

I also run the following commands before i reach the clone statement:

```
git_process = git.Git(**path to folder to be pushed later on to git**)
git_process.update_environment(SSH_KEY=SSH_PRIVATE_KEY)
```

Where SSH_PRIVATE_KEY is the path to the private key.

What am i missing ?

Thanks !

Comment: Your ssh command is failing. I feel like this more of a ssh problem than an actual GitPython library one.

Comment: Is there a solution ? It seems like the only option is to use subprocess library and run it in the cmd but my intention is to be OS-independent.

Comment: Can you connect to the server with ssh and this private key but without git? It could be [wrong key format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2224066/7976758).

Comment: Try the cli command in bash.  
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i /home/user/test_private_key" git clone ssh://git@git_domain:1399/project/repo.git /home/user/git_download -v

If this fails, then its an issue with your ssh authentication.