# SSH Key connection on Debian VPS with Windows cmd

Tags: ssh, cmd, window, putty, ssh-keys

I have a Debian VPS on which I have installed SSH keys. I would like to connect to it with Windows cmd and not Putty.

To connect I use :

```
ssh $USER@$SERVEUR -p $PORT -i C:\Users\Path\to\my\key.ppk
```

But in return I have :

```
Load key "C:\\Users\\path\\to\\my\\key.ppk": invalid format
```

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2224066/850848

Comment: Note that your question is [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally found the solution. The problem is that Putty does not read the keys generated by OpenSSH on Windows and vice versa. Once generated, just authorize one or more keys to connect via Windows or Putty.

Thanks to the guy who downgraded my request without helping me.