# Putty and rsa public key error on new windows machine

Tags: rsa, putty

I got a new Windows computer and installed putty on it. I exported the registry keys from the old computer and imported them to recover the Putty connections and avoid adding them manually.

I also copied the rsa public key .ppk to the new computer and selected it in the Auth section in putty, but I get the following error:

> Unable to use key file "c:\path\to\id_rsa.ppk" (unable to open file)

I'm temped to regenerate the key pair again in the VPS server but I thought public keys could be used by any computer!

Am I missing something? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit:

Plink output (plink -v username@hostname -i "c:\path\to\id_rsa.ppk") as requested by @Martin Prikryl:

`We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.70
Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
Using SSH protocol version 2
Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and hash SHA-256
Server also has ssh-ed25519/ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 host keys, but we don't know any of them
Host key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 24:2a:c3:65:b9:9a:3e:5f:59:fc:dc:15:42:31:0b:a0
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption`
`Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm
Reading key file "D:\path\to\id_rsa.ppk"
Using username "user".
Offered public key
Offer of public key accepted
Authenticating with public key "imported-openssh-key"
Sent public key signature
Access granted
Opening session as main channel
Opened main channel
Allocated pty (ospeed 38400bps, ispeed 38400bps)
Started a shell/command`

Edit 2:

putty.exe -v username@hostname -i "c:\path\to\id_rsa.ppk" throws a timeout error.

Comment: What do you get if you do `plink -v username@hostname -i "c:\path\to\id_rsa.ppk"`?

Comment: Sorry I missed this comment. I get connection using your command, but I get weird characters. Does that have something to do with the shell?

`]0;user@vpsxxxxx: ~user@vpsxxxxx:~$ ls
google07fda122cca02bf8.html  [0m[01;31msitepress-multilingual-cms.4.0.4.zip[0m
[01;34mhtml[0m                         [01;34mthemeswp[0m
]0;user@vpsxxxxx: ~user@vpsxxxxx:~$ ]0;user@vpsxxxxx: ~user@vpsxxxxx:~$`

Comment: I was interested in the authentication part of the output. The part you posted is irrelevant in the context of this question.

Comment: My bad, there you go:

`We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.70
Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
Using SSH protocol version 2
Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and hash SHA-256
Server also has ssh-ed25519/ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 host keys, but we don't know any of them
Host key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 24:2a:c3:65:b9:9a:3e:5f:59:fc:dc:15:42:31:0b:a0
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption`

Comment: `Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm
Reading key file "D:\path\to\id_rsa.ppk"
Using username "user".
Offered public key
Offer of public key accepted
Authenticating with public key "imported-openssh-key"
Sent public key signature
Access granted
Opening session as main channel
Opened main channel
Allocated pty (ospeed 38400bps, ispeed 38400bps)
Started a shell/command`

Comment: Please edit this into your question.

Comment: OK, so now, if you do the very same using PuTTY: `putty -v username@hostname -i "c:\path\to\id_rsa.ppk"` - What do you get in PuTTY event log?

Comment: A putty window pops up in black and and after a while I get a timeout error.

Comment: Oh sorry and event log is not written I don't understand why... I'm starting to think the issue has to do with importing the old machine's putty settings by exporting and importing the windows registry entries? Could this be causing the anomaly?

Comment: So try to export/backup and delete everything in `HKCU/Software/SimonTatham/PuTTY/Sessions`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you didn't "select" the key on the *Connection > SSH > Auth* page.

You have rather typed key name there only, without a path. So PuTTY cannot find it.

You need to use a full path to the key file, like `C:\path\to\id_rsa.ppk`.

Comment: I just shortened the message when I pasted it here because no one needs to know the full path where I store the key. Thanks for trying though :)

Comment: So use a path placeholder in your question, to make that clear!

Answer (score -1):

Following this [link](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/50):

```
You used Putty Private Key format (.ppk)
Convert your ppk to Openssh Key File (id_rsa)
```

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224066/how-to-convert-ssh-keypairs-generated-using-puttygen-windows-into-key-pairs-us/2224204#2224204) is an explanation how to do it. Hope it helps.

Comment: OP is using PuTTY, so OP needs to use keys in PPK format, not OpenSSH format.

Comment: What @MartinPrikryl said.