# dbForge Studio for MySql - wrong key format error

Tags: mysql, ssh, ssh-keys, dbforge

I am trying to connect to dbForge using ssh private key, but for some reason I am getting error **Wrong key format**.
I generated keys using cmd, and my private key has .ppk extension. I checked everything using puttyGen and all looks good.
I do not know what could be the solution for this?

My private ssh key is: **marko_ssh_key.ppk**
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert SSH keypairs generated using PuTTYgen (Windows) into key-pairs used by ssh-agent and Keychain (Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224066/how-to-convert-ssh-keypairs-generated-using-puttygen-windows-into-key-pairs-us)

Comment: I did that, and when I try to connect, I am getting this error message: The passphrase is wrong or key file is broken. Passphrase seems to work fine, cause I use it every time when I open dbForge. So what does it mean that key file is broken? Thanks! @user1191247

Comment: Try following https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/putty/windows/puttygen and/or https://docs.devart.com/studio-for-mysql/connecting-to-db/creating-ssh-connection.html#ssh-connection-using-public-key-authentication

Comment: Now I am getting only this Incorrect key passphrase message, but when I open and edit key using puttyGen and enter that passphrase, it works good. @user1191247

Comment: Have you confirmed that you can SSH to the server using that key for authentication?

Comment: Yes, I can SSH to the server using that key. @user1191247